# Install orfeo toolbox in python3.7

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I want to orthorectify some images taken by drones using python and wherever I have looked, otb seems to be the only sensible option. But unfortunately I haven't been able to install it on my python to run.

What I did was:

1. Downloaded official otb package for windows
2. Created virtual env in pycharm for python 3.7
3. Went to directory of otb through pycharm terminal and typed otbenv.bat
4. But this does nothing for me,
   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Ck7.png]

I know I am missing something painfully obvious so please help me.

Comment: have you tried running it as an admin?

Comment: Yes and that results in the same error as well. For reference, I have followed this article https://simonwrigley.medium.com/how-to-install-orfeo-toolbox-for-use-with-python-anaconda-on-windows-8c866b3e8aaa

Answer (score 0):

After binding, Start python and check python version to double check in virtual env prompt.

```
python
```

Then

```
import otbApplication as otb
```

with this prompt you can use otb in python